# Selenium driver returns empty promise instead of element

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I have next query:
`document.getElementsByClassName('calendar')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nupz5.png)

Trying to return this value via selenium framework (NodeJs):

```
let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser("chrome")
        .build();

driver.executeAsyncScript(
        "document.getElementsByClassName('calendar')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes",
        it => console.log("result --> " + it)
    );
```

But, unfortunatly, I see an empty Promise instead. Also, tried another way with x-path, but result still the same:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@class=\"calendar\"]")) // Empty promise
```

How can I retrieve this element?

Comment: I bet, but I'm not certain, that the problem is that *nodes* can't be serialized. Try replacing `.childNodes",` with `.childNodes[0].textContent",` just to see if that fixes it

Comment: @CertainPerformance unfortunatly it's not working. Also I tried `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("calendar")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes)` - result is the same.